# "Actually, he's just..." or "Actually, he just..."?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A: How's it going with you and Toby?

B: Great. Actually, he's just moved in with me.

Can I say "Actually, **he's** just..." or should it just be "**he**"?

Comment: The word ***actually*** AND the contraction ***he's*** are both irrelevant to the syntactic issue here, which is simply that Simple Past ***He moved in*** and Present Perfect ***He has moved in*** are often equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [He {went / has gone / had gone} out 5 minutes ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70013/he-went-has-gone-had-gone-out-5-minutes-ago)

Comment: I wonder if you know what he's means.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either **he's** *or* **he just** depending on the time period of the person who has moved in, but you can't use both **he's**  *and* **just**.

> He's moved in...

This will mean that ***he has moved in for few weeks or months***, whereas,

> He just moved in...

This will mean that ***he has moved in few days ago*** which is why you use *just*.

Comment: Not sure where you got that idea. "Have just done something" is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: "He has" = present perfect = Started in the past, continuing in the present. "Just" = happened recently. There's no clash conflict these two.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: As a native speaker, I hear people say things like "he's just..." all the time. It doesn't sound the least bit wrong to my ear. I would like to point out that in your final paragraph, you actually use the perfect to describe exactly the same situation, so it's not semantically wrong, either.